# Is composition and aggegation are a form of association?

Tags: c++, oop

I am a bit confused on association. People say that HAS-A relationship is classified as the following - Association, aggregation and composition. However, I feel that Aggregation and composition are nothing but a form of association. In my opinion, HAS-A relationship can be broadly said as association. The association can be further classified as the following -  Aggregation and composition. Am I correct on it?

Type of association -

1. Aggregation.
2. Composition.

Aggregation example - water bottle has a water. Water can still exist even when the container, water bottle is destroyed.

Composition example - Heart of the human body. If human body is destroyed, the heart will also destroy. I know that heart transplantation is also possible. However, keeping that principle aside, this example should be good enough.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> People say that HAS-A relationship is classified as the following - Association, aggregation and composition.

Whom - any references?  An Association can be something like the bi-directional relationship between a specific flight-route (e.g. Tokyo to Paris), and a specific plane.  Clearly there's no "has-a" relationship there... no ownership as in Composition nor part/whole relationship as in Aggregation... they're equals in the relationship.

> However, I feel that Aggregation and composition are nothing but a form of association.

Aggregation and Composition *are* forms of Association, but that's not to say that they're "nothing but" forms of Association - they also convey other functionality such as ownership and potentially encapsulation.

> In my opinion, HAS-A relationship can be broadly said as association. The association can be further classified as the following - Aggregation and composition.  Am I correct on it?

No, I wouldn't say you were correct.  You can say that a "has-a" relationship is a form of Association, but not that the two things are equivalent; Association is the superset, containing "has-a" relationships and other forms of Association too.